# What is the significance of Schmendrick calling the unicorn Amalthea in The Last Unicorn?

Tags: names, the-last-unicorn

I'm aware that Beagle borrowed the name from a [Greek goddess](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiMg4ax59fSAhUr1oMKHXR0AIAQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAmalthea_(mythology)&usg=AFQjCNFDYf49w4fcpSk5NNgeVa5mG-DGOg) by the same name, but I cannot determine a connection outside of that (Wikipedia's entry is also rather short, and I can't seem to find anything better on my own). I get the feeling the name is supposed to evoke a motherly feel for the character, but I'm curious about what other significance this name has for the character.

Comment: Gah. I'd put together a really nice answer, then realised that the author had directly answered the question at the back of the bloody book. On th plus side, I was exactly correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was directly addressed by the author in an afternote in the new Deluxe ebook edition of The Last Unicorn.

> **Connor:** *Let’s talk about character names, then. Your readers have been speculating about them for decades. When the unicorn becomes
> human, and Schmendrick calls her the Lady Amalthea‌—‌where did that
> come from?*
>
> **Peter:** *It’s funny about the names, because **at the time they just came to me, and mostly I didn’t realize why they were appropriate
> until later. Amalthea sounded good, and I had some vague recollection
> that it came from Greek mythology‌**—‌it’s the name of the goat who
> nursed the infant god Zeus when he was being hidden from his father,
> who wanted to eat him. This wise goat fed the baby, sheltered him, and
> played with him. But at the time I decided to use the name, I’d
> forgotten the rest of the story‌—‌that when Zeus got older and was
> acquiring his full godly strength he became too much for the goat to
> romp and wrestle with, and at some point he accidentally broke off one
> of her horns. He was immediately apologetic, of course, and turned the
> broken-off horn into the cornucopia‌—‌the Horn of Plenty. But **Amalthea
> only had one horn from then on, so in a real sense she was the first
> unicorn.***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Last Unicorn: The Deluxe Edition](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Last-Unicorn-Peter-S-Beagle/dp/1613771355)</sup></sub>

---

According to Britannica, [Amalthea](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Amalthaea) is sometimes represented as a goat (or possibly a nymph goatherd) who raised the young Zeus, and tore a horn off of her own head (or one of her goat's heads) to make a cornucopia.

For someone versed in the classics, this would be a most appropriate name for someone that you wished to associate with both **high levels of femininity** and, critically, **the possession of one horn.**

> *Amalthaea, in Greek (originally Cretan) mythology, the foster mother
> of Zeus, king of the gods. She is sometimes represented as the goat
> that suckled the infant god in a cave in Crete, sometimes as a nymph
> who fed him the milk of a goat. **This goat having broken off one of its
> horns, Amalthaea filled the horn with flowers and fruits and presented
> it to Zeus,** who, according to one version, placed it, together with
> the goat, among the stars. In general, the horn was regarded as the
> symbol of inexhaustible riches and plenty and became the attribute of
> various divinities and of rivers as fertilizers of the land.*

[image]

Comment: Wow. From the first unicorn to "the last". This is incredibly well put together. Thank you so, so much. ^-^